# Call function outside in React Native

Tags: javascript, function, react-native

I have a React Native application and I need to call a function in `HomeScreen` definition to do something with it's elements. This action should be done by custom widget that is stored outside `HomeScreen`. I try to call the function from the widget's props, but it returns `undefined`. So, how can I propperly do this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Modal } from 'react-native';
import { LongPressGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function HomeScreen() {

  const doSomething = () => {
    console.log("Works");
  }

  return (
    <View style={{padding: 30}}>
      <LongPress
        action={() => {doSomething()}}
      >
        <View>
          <Text>Long press me</Text>
        </View>
      </LongPress>
    </View>
  );
};

function LongPress({children}, props) {
  return (
    <LongPressGestureHandler
      onHandlerStateChange={() => {HomeScreen.action}}
      minDurationMs={700}
    >
      <View>{children}</View>
    </LongPressGestureHandler>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you pass an `action` prop to your `LongPress` component. Assuming that's the function you need to fire, the following should suffice:

```
function LongPress({action, children}) {
  return (
    <LongPressGestureHandler
      onHandlerStateChange={action}
      minDurationMs={700}
    >
      <View>{children}</View>
    </LongPressGestureHandler>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PubSub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js).

```js
class DownloadManager{
    public static pointer;


    async download() {
        //download code
        //when download update
        PubSub.publish('download-complete', {status:true});
    }
}

class BackupPage extends React.Component<any, any> {

    componentDidMount() {
        PubSub.subscribe('download-complete', (msg, data) => {
            this.setState({ status :data.status})
        })
    }

    render() {
        //render code
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this library can solve my problem. I just need to call function from another one.

Comment: This library will send an event and it will be catch by its subscriber. It will serve what you need.

Comment: Is it impossible to fix this problem without connecting any library?

Comment: I haven't used this. However, You can give try https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/different-ways-to-dispatch-actions-with-redux